# How to update a union type in Elm?

Tags: elm

If I have a

```
type Status 
    = Open Time 
    | Closed 

type alias Time = { open : Int , closed : Int , message : Maybe String } 
data : List Status
```

and I want to update a `Status` record on `data`

and I have a function that gets me the record I want to update, how do I then update a union type, where `record` is a `Status`?

Comment: You don't update a union type. You replace it.

Comment: You don't modify _any_ value in Elm. Everything is immutable, so you can only create new values. That's an essential property of the language as a whole.

Comment: Can you perhaps flesh out your code example a bit more. Hard to know what exactly you're asking. Sounds like you're asking about record update sytax `{ someRecord | someField = newVal }` or how to change a single value in a `List`.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, you cannot update a Union type since types are not mutable like in OOP. Instead, you have to replace it with a shiny brand new one and put it in its container (most often a Record).

```
-- the container for the Status type
type alias Store = {status: Status, name: String}

-- type that cannot be modified, only replaced with new instances
type Status 
    = Open Time 
    | Closed 

type alias Time = { open : Int, closed : Int, message : Maybe String } 

starbucks = openStore {name: "StarBucks", status: Closed}

-- close down the store to prevent kids from feeling cool
closeStore store = 
  {store | status = Closed}

-- open a store to help a multinational extract value from your country
openStore store = 
  {store | status = Open {open: 9, closed: 18, message: Just "Get your sugar injection here!"}}
```